# Is it possible to search for keyboard shortcuts by a keybind (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to find all shortcuts that are using a specific keybinding in an easy and reliable way.

In Visual Studio the only reliable way I've found so far is by changing a shortcut's keybinding and get list of shortcuts using the same keybinding. I think it's too roundabout and I'm looking for a way similar to VS Code.

In VS Code in the Keyboard Shortcuts tab you can search by a keybinding (by writing "Ctrl + R" for example) and you will get all shortcuts using that keybinding.

Is there a similar way to do this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you open Visual Studio keyboard options and **Press shortcut keys** in the corresponding box, in the **Shortcut currently used by** list you will see all commands for this shortcut:

[image]

Comment: That is, **first click on the 'Press shortcut keys' textbox** and then press the key combination you want to search for.