# In Visual Studio 2022, pressing F5 to continue while in debugger mode adds a tab character in the text editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, tabs

When my code hits a breakpoint and i press F5 to continue the code execution, Visual Studio often adds a tab character at the beginning of line as if i had pressed the Tab key on my keyboard.

for example:

```
if (my_condition)
{ <--- my breakpoint is here

   // my code
}
```

becomes :

```
if (my_condition)
    { <--- my breakpoint is here

   // my code
}
```

Now, there is a Tab character before the { character. It adds another and another every time my breakpoint is hit and i press F5 to continue the execution. It doesnt happen every single time, but quite often and the issue is driving me insane.

I havent found anything online about this issue.

Comment: Do you have some external tool that has macro capabilities? If you open Notepad and hit F5 a bunch of times, does it add a tab? You could also [lookup which keyboard shortcut F5 is used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069929/is-it-possible-to-search-for-keyboard-shortcuts-by-a-keybind-visual-studio-2017) and also reset your keybindings in VS.

Comment: @gunr2171 i have no macros. its a recent install of windows 10 and i havent downloaded any other program than what i need for work. i looked at the current shortcuts tied to F5 and there are none that would add a Tab in front of my line of code

Comment: What about resetting?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT i removed all the actions related to the F5 shortcut in visual studio. Then i added the Debug.Start shortcut only. the problem is still there.

Comment: Try using option-> import and export -> reset.